# Regex for substring with same start and order

Tags: regex, go

I have a string "abcdefg". I'd like to match any substring that is equivalent to removing characters at the end. So in addition to matching "abcdefg", the strings "abc", "a", and "abcd" should all match.

Using `a|ab|abc|abcd|abcde|abcdef|abcdefg` will work, but it is essentially just a list of strings.

Is there a more space efficient way to do this?

Additionally, I can't use lookaheads/lookbehinds as they are not supported in Go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd code up a check by hand. Regexes aren't really a good tool for this. But you know, if you insist...

```
a(b(c(d(e(f(g)?)?)?)?)?)?
```

Comment: I love it! Also, easy to programatically generate this from the full string.

Comment: I'd love to be able to write a check, but I'm not actually writing code. I'm using a service written in Go (which I found out after lookaheads didn't work), where "abcdefg" is part of a larger regex. I realized should probably allow substrings of "abcdefg", but there is a character limit for the regex, so this is helpful as a shorter alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You effectively want to use [`strings.HasPrefix`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#HasPrefix) to check if the string is a prefix of `"abcdefg"`. You also need to ensure the string is non-empty, since the empty string is always a valid prefix:

```golang
match := s != "" && strings.HasPrefix("abcdefg", s)
```

This will be much faster than using a regular expression.